# Is there a way to get around the background-position: bottom; -bug in Safari 8 (on OS X Yosemite)?

Tags: html, css, safari, osx-yosemite

Safari 8 on OS X Yosemite seems to have a really annoying bug when rendering web pages with `background-position: bottom;` in CSS.

Somehow the background is positioned about **60 px below the bottom of the page** and it's really messing up the look of some sites I've made earlier.

Is there a workaround to address this bug, for example by targeting Safari 8 specifically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce it on jsfiddle, but here's an example (background image has measurements starting from the bottom): http://kallekilponen.pp.fi/safari8/

Comment: Any ideas how to get around this?  Safari 8.0.4 is out but it seems Apple still hasn't addressed this bug.

Comment: To answer myself I had to make a temporary fix by using a image I positioned to z-index: 0; and disabled pointer events. Not the best elegant solution, but gets around the bug. I can't believe Apple still hasn't addressed the bug.